# How to audit when a particular program / exe is run

Tags: audit, landesk

I want to audit our users computers for when a particular program is run, kind of like getting a more detailed report on the lines of the "Used Rarely / Occasionally" type you see in Add/Remove Programs.

I want to be able to see a list of when the program is run, to get some statistical info on when the users tend to run it.

So, something like:

ABC.EXE
Run 09:12 21/08/11
Run 11:32 21/08/11

etc.

I have access to LANDesk, but don't know if this could do it - or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you can audit disk, folder and even separates files then later you can check it using the Event Viewer.

[image]

However, you must do it manually for each executable that you want to track.

Answer (score 0):

In the current LANDESK version 9.6 and newer, you can set up "monitored" applications, which you can specify by name. It will then log the last time that the application was run, along with how long it is used. This is part of the Software License Monitoring tool